# Boot file system partition at the begining of the hard drive

Tags: debian, dual-boot, partition-table

My hard drive have Windows, Ubuntu and Debian installed. For some reason Debian is not showed in the grub list. If I use a bootable grub rescue software, it shows a message like this "Please create a boot partition greater than 200 Mb at the beginning of the disk". What is the size recommended for this partition? "greater than 200 Mb" is not particularly specific. 
The beginning of the disk contains the Windows partition. I am afraid that creating a Linux made Boot partition could break Windows. Have somebody been previously in this situation?

```
   Model: ATA TOSHIBA-TR200 (scsi) Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB Sector size
    logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: msdos Disk Flags: 


Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1     1049kB  86,8GB  86,8GB  primary   ntfs  
4     86,8GB  240GB   153GB   extended 
11    86,8GB  87,9GB  1081MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)  
5     87,9GB  105GB   16,8GB  logical   ext4  
6     105GB   116GB   11,8GB  logical   ext4  
7     116GB   131GB   14,8GB  logical   ext4  
8     131GB   147GB   15,5GB  logical   ext4  
9     147GB   198GB   51,7    logical   ext4 
10    198GB   240GB   41,6GB  logical   ext4
```

Comment: Is this a UEFI or legacy boot system?

Comment: Was this message from Boot-Repair? It still suggest a boot partition inside the first 137GB of a drive. But that really only applies to old BIOS based systems. Have not seen issue with any newer UEFI based system. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred Yes It was Boot repair. I edited the question with the output of the command. I will give a try to create a boot partition inside the first 137Gb

Comment: @kemotep legay boot system

Comment: Unless really old system, may not need separate /boot partition. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Only use advanced options to update system. Auto fix will just default to first system seen.